# How do I make the Animation Tree play animations from the beginning? Godot 3.2.3

Tags: animation, tree, godot

I have set up a simple animation tree. It starts with an idle that has the character doing various things. When I move the character I have it "travel" to a running animation which works great, but when I travel back to idle, the idle animation picks up exactly where it left off instead of starting from the beginning.

When using an animation tree, how to I make the animations start from their beginning instead of from their last position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out if you don't have a return path to your animation, then that's why it just plays from where it left off. So make sure you have a return path and it will play from the beginning.